# PySide2 change QLabel text by clicking QPushButton

Tags: python-3.x, pyside2

I'm trying to change QLabel text by clicking QPushbutton.
I installed PySide2==5.15.2.1
Python 3.7.6 32bit in Windows 10 environment.

First, I made UI class (well, I didn't used Qt designer so I don't have *.ui file)

```
import PySide2.QtWidgets as qtw
...

class UI_MainWindow(object):
 def setupUI(self, MainWindow):
   window = qtw.QWidget()
   someButton = qtw.QPushButton("button")
   someLabel = qtw.QLabel("---")
...
   MainWindow.setCentralWidget(window)
```

And there is some other class who has functions and connects as below

```
import PySide2.QtWidgets as qtw
from uiSomething import UI_MainWindow #uiSomething is a name of the file of the code above, who has UI_MainWindow class.
...

class something(qtw.QMainWindow, UI_MainWindow):
 def __init__(self):
   super(something, self).__init__()

   self.ui = UI_MainWindow()
   self.ui.setupUI(self)

   self.someButton.clicked.connect(self.function) # not working. ui.someButton... also not working.
   #if I put this connect in UI_MainWindow, at least connect works.

 def function(self):
   self.ui.someLabel.setText("change text") # not working. ui.someLabel...also not working.
```

and the other file, I put main function

```
import Something
import PySide2.QtWidgets as qtw
...

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app = qtw.QApplication()
   MainWindow = Something.something()

   MainWindow.show()

   app.exec__()
```

However, it just give me an error message as below when I click the button.
AttributeEror: 'UI_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'someLabel'
I thought it's okay to define every widgets in setupUI function but probably not..?

Please let me know if there is any idea.
Thank you in advance!

Best wishes,
JESuh

Comment: That `UI_MainWindow` should create instance attributes, while `someLabel` is a local variable. You tried to manually edit the file generated by pyuic, haven't you? Doing so is considered bad practice (and there's a clear warning in the header of those files that explicitly says that you should not do that).

Comment: If you created the `UI_MainWindow` class yourself, you should understand what the error message means and how to fix it. This has nothing to do with PyQt/PySide as such: it just requires [elementary knowledge of Python tracebacks](https://realpython.com/python-traceback/). If you want to know how to create the PyQt/PySide UI class properly, you should learn [how to use Qt Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Answer (score 0):

Because **someButton** and **someLabel** are not declared as class attributes. These variables are only accessible within the function(setupUI). Objects created from UI_MainWidow cannot call or modify them. Not even if you create a subclass of UI_MainWindow.

**Change**

```
import PySide2.QtWidgets as qtw
...

class UI_MainWindow(object):
 def setupUI(self, MainWindow):
   window = qtw.QWidget()
   someButton = qtw.QPushButton("button")
   someLabel = qtw.QLabel("---")
...
   MainWindow.setCentralWidget(window)
```

**To**

```
import PySide2.QtWidgets as qtw
...

class UI_MainWindow(object):
 def setupUI(self, MainWindow):
   window = qtw.QWidget()
   self.someButton = qtw.QPushButton("button")
   self.someLabel = qtw.QLabel("---")
...
   MainWindow.setCentralWidget(window)
```

Answer (score 0):

@blaqICE's answer is a good start but I'm noticing a handful of other things that are contributing to your issues.

The main things I'm seeing are your use of **class inheritance** and **instance attributes**. Overall organization seems to be working against you as well. The way you're doing it is workable but it gets confusing pretty quickly. I'm not sure how familiar you are with creating classes but I would spend some time in the [python classes docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/classes.html) and looking at [PySide example code](https://realpython.com/learning-paths/pyqt-gui-programming/).

---

If you want to fix your code the way it is all you need to do is fix the lines I commented on:

**uiSomething.py**

```
import PySide2.QtWidgets as qtw


class UI_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUI(self, MainWindow):  # consider using __init__ instead
        self.window = qtw.QWidget()  # make an instance attribute for later access with your class instance; not needed with __init__ and proper inheritance

        self.main_layout = qtw.QVBoxLayout()  # create a layout to hold everything
        self.window.setLayout(self.main_layout)  # set 'self.window' layout to the new 'self.main_layout'

        self.someButton = qtw.QPushButton("button")  # make an instance attribute for later access with your class instance
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.someButton)  # add 'self.someButton' to 'self.main_layout'

        self.someLabel = qtw.QLabel("---")  # make an instance attribute for later access with your class instance
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.someLabel)  # add 'self.someLabel' to 'self.main_layout'

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.window)
```

**Something.py**

```
from uiSomething import UI_MainWindow

class something(qtw.QMainWindow, UI_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(something, self).__init__()
        self.ui = UI_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUI(self)  # consider using __init__ in class definition instead; this line would not be needed

        self.ui.someButton.clicked.connect(self.function)  # 'self.ui' before 'someButton' to access instance's someButton

    def function(self):
        self.ui.someLabel.setText("change text")  # this is fine
        # this was not working because of the issue with someButton's signal connection
```

**main.py**

```
import Something
import PySide2.QtWidgets as qtw
# import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app = qtw.QApplication()
   MainWindow = Something.something()

   MainWindow.show()

   app.exec_()  # only one underscore; typically done as 'sys.exit(app.exec_())' to formally exit python interpreter
```

---

However, a better implementation would be:

**uiSomething.py**

```
import PySide2.QtWidgets as qtw


class UI_MainWidget(qtw.QWidget):  # UI_MainWindow -> UI_MainWidget for clarity; inherit QWidget
    def __init__(self, button_text="button", lable_click_text="change text", parent=None):  # auto initialize object
        super(UI_MainWidget, self).__init__(parent)  # pass parent to inherited class __init__ function
        # 'self.window' no longer needed due to __init__ and can be accessed simply through 'self'
        self.parent = parent  # set parent as instance variable for later use if needed
        self.button_text = button_text  # set custom arguments as instance variable for later use if needed
        self.lable_click_text = lable_click_text  # set custom arguments as instance variable for later use if needed

        self.main_layout = qtw.QVBoxLayout()  # create a layout to hold everything
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)  # set the widget's layout to the new self.main_layout

        self.someButton = qtw.QPushButton(self.button_text)  # class argument for easy customization of other instances
        self.someButton.clicked.connect(self.function)  # moved to instantiation class for clarity and ease of access
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.someButton)

        self.someLabel = qtw.QLabel("---")  # placeholder text
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.someLabel)

        # moved '.setCentralWidget(self)' to main window class for organization and ease of access

    def function(self):  # move to instantiation class for clarity, organization, and ease of access
        # 'self.ui' no longer needed in instantiation class, use 'self' instead
        self.someLabel.setText(self.lable_click_text)  # class argument for easy customization of other instances
```

**Something.py**

```
import PySide2.QtWidgets as qtw  # need to import module here as well due to inheritance
from uiSomething import UI_MainWidget


# for this class, double inheritance doesn't really have any effect. Stick with the main one it represents.
class UI_MainWindow(qtw.QMainWindow):  # something -> UI_MainWindow for clarity; inherit QMainWindow only; PEP 8 naming
    def __init__(self, parent=None):  # added parent kwarg for parenting to other widgets if needed
        super(UI_MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)  # pass parent to inherited class __init__ function
        self.ui = UI_MainWidget(parent=self)
        # self.ui.setupUI(self)  # no longer needed due to __init__; can delete

        # using custom class keyword arguments
        # self.ui = UI_MainWidget(button_text="new button name", lable_click_text="new button clicked", parent=self)
        # self.ui = UI_MainWidget(button_text="another button name", lable_click_text="another button clicked", parent=self)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.ui)
```

**main.py**

```
import Something
import PySide2.QtWidgets as qtw
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app = qtw.QApplication()
   MainWindow = Something.UI_MainWindow()
   MainWindow.show()

   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```